# Is there a way to get v-for object values from a component prop?

Tags: vue.js, vue-props

first of all, I'm not fully familiarized with vue, so maybe I'm just saying dumb things. I need to access a value from an object obtained by a v-for from another component prop. I have the following template code:

```
        <v-sheet v-for="item in itemsArray" :key="item.id" class="d-flex px-md-8 px-sm-0 w-100">
                    <!-- icon -->
                    <v-avatar :color="itemTypesData[item.item_type.name].color" :size="iconHeight"
                        class="ma-1 flex-shrink-0">
                        <v-icon color="white" size="x-large">{{ itemTypesData[item.item_type.name].icon }}</v-icon>
                    </v-avatar>
        </v-sheet>
```

Where itemTypesData is an enum containing specific properties for each item_type. The problem here is that when I try to access to the item.item_type.name enum element, it can't get that value. Is there any way to do it? I set the itemsArray as reactive and so, I'm sure that I'm missing something but I can't find what.ç

itemsArray content:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "order": 0,
    "version": null,
    "item_type": { "id": 2, "name": "type1", "description": null }
  }
  ,
  {
    "id": 2,
    "order": 0,
    "version": null,
    "item_type": { "id": 1, "name": "type2", "description": null }
  }
]
```

thank you!

Comment: hey mate, ca you post the content of `itemsArray`?

Comment: Hey @NikolaPavicevic, just updated it with example data, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how `itemTypesData` looks like, but you can look at snippet with my interpretation:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    itemsArray: [
      {
        id: 1,
        order: 0,
        version: null,
        item_type: { id: 2, name: 'type1', description: null },
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        order: 0,
        version: null,
        item_type: { id: 1, name: 'type2', description: null },
      },
    ],
    itemTypesData: {
      type1: { color: 'blue', icon: '1' },
      type2: { color: 'red', icon: '2' },
    },
    iconHeight: 30,
  }),
})
```

```html
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-sheet
          v-for="item in itemsArray"
          :key="item.id"
          class="d-flex px-md-8 px-sm-0 w-100"
        >
          <!-- icon -->
          <v-avatar
            :color="itemTypesData[item.item_type.name].color"
            :size="iconHeight"
            class="ma-1 flex-shrink-0"
          >
            <v-icon color="white" size="x-large"
              >{{ itemTypesData[item.item_type.name].icon }}</v-icon
            >
          </v-avatar>
        </v-sheet>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```